# finding voltage peak to peak using v(t)

Tags: voltage

My formula is v(t)=10cos(30*pi*t). My theory is that Vmax is the 10 which means Vpp is 10V and -10V. Since the formula for v(t) = vmcos(w*t+theta)

Comment: 10 is the peak; 20 is the peak-to-peak. What's your actual question?

Comment: Yeah, you forgot to ask a question!

Comment: Sorry the asking for the peak to peak was my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For \$ v(t)=10cos(30 \pi t) \$ the maximum the \$ cos \$ function can return is *1*.

Therefore \$ V_{p} = 10 \ \text V\$ and \$ V_{p-p} = 20 \ \text V\$.

Answer (score 0):

10 is peak and 20 is peak to peak.